# Quartz.Net failed on server

Tags: .net-6.0, quartz.net

I have quartz jobs configured in .Net6 web application. Jobs runs correctly on local computer but site crashes when deployed to server.

[image]

both local and server computers have runtime 6.0.10 installed.
I see below error in logs.

```
System.ArgumentException: cronExpression cannot be null
   at Quartz.CronExpression..ctor(String cronExpression)
   at Quartz.CronExpression.ValidateExpression(String cronExpression)
   at Quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(String cronExpression)
   at Quartz.TriggerExtensions.WithCronSchedule(ITriggerConfigurator triggerBuilder, String cronExpression, Action`1 action)
   at Pcc.Preferences.App.Startup.<ConfigureQuartz>b__16_4(ITriggerConfigurator trigger) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/Source/v2/Application/Startup.cs:line 455
   at Quartz.ServiceCollectionExtensions.ScheduleJob[T](IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator options, Action`1 trigger, Action`1 job)
   at Pcc.Preferences.App.Startup.<ConfigureQuartz>b__16_1(IServiceCollectionQuartzConfigurator quartz) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/Source/v2/Application/Startup.cs:line 454
   at Quartz.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddQuartz(IServiceCollection services, NameValueCollection properties, Action`1 configure)
   at Quartz.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddQuartz(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/1801). Sad to see such cross-posting.

Comment: yes , thanks for answering. I will confirm if it works for me soon. Is cross-posting an issue? should I remove this post ?